# Passing multiple tags with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

OK I have a specific situation. I am using a custom class to create some buttons and I can set their tag property with unique numbers like:

```
button.tag =[NSNumber numberWithInt:[10]];
```

This is very useful in another part of my program because I can access this unique tag like:

```
UIButton *clicked= (UIButton *) sender;

ButtonTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", clicked.tag];
```

Now I want to pass one more unique property  just like this. I am making this up but this is how I envision it

```
button.tagCREATED_BY_ME =[NSNumber numberWithInt:[9000]];
```

The question might be poorly worded but I don't know any better so I called it "tag".(correct wording might be element/property etc) How do I create a similar property to function just like .tag?

Thanks a lot!
arda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your subclassed/custom button, you can add a string property or even an integer property whichever you feel good.

```
@interface CustomButton: ....
       ...
       @property(strong) NSString *createdBy;

@end
```

Then you can access those as `aButton.createdBy`

Comment: This is very simple and working. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

## CALayer allows [Key-Value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html) actually.

You can literally just do this (on any **UI** object):

`[button.layer setValue:@(9000) forKey:@"tagCREATED_BY_ME"];`

and to read it just use

`[button.layer valueForKey:@"tagCREATED_BY_ME"]`

---

---

---

## *Obligatory, the above is all you need to get this up and going, you're good to go.*

For others, more advanced /or/ specific stuff follows:

If you need these keys to have a **default** value when nothing has yet been assigned to them... You can set these custom "tags" *(eh)* to have default return values if you name them according to a pattern. For example I start all of my layer keys name's with "customKey_". So the above would have been @"customKey_tagCREATED_BY_ME", then you can have your .m file return the default key values for any standard key like `masksToBounds` but then return a very specific value for your keys (aka keys that start with "customKey_") with the following method:

```
+(id)defaultValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"customKey_"]) {
        return @(0);
    }
    return [CALayer defaultValueForKey:key];
}
```

The reason you have to have a naming pattern (like always having the prefix "customKey_") is so you don't interfere with a CALayer's natural properties like `.size` and `.backgroundColor`, etc. Your default value you want returned will only be returned on properties (key) starting with "customKey_" or whatever naming pattern you use.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to achieve?

There is the possibility of adding an associative references. The good part about this, is that you don't need to sub-class it. So, start by creating a Category for the `UIButton`:

```
@interface UIButton (ExtraTag)

@property (nonatomic, retain) id extraTag;

@end
```

And the .m:

```
static char const * const ExtraTagKey = "ExtraTag";

@implementation UIButton (ExtraTag)
@dynamic extraTag;

- (id)extraTag {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, ExtraTagKey);
}

- (void)setExtraTag:(id)newExtraTag {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, ExtraTagKey, newExtraTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

[You can check the article I used](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/).

Comment: Nice trick. I was used this but I was not able to add the associated key. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Associated references instead of tags manipulation

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char kThumbnailButtonAssociatedPhotoKey;

// ...

- (void)setAssociatedPhoto:(Photo *)associatedPhoto
        forThumbnailButton:(UIButton *)thumbnailButton
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(thumbnailButton,
                             &kThumbnailButtonAssociatedPhotoKey,
                             associatedPhoto,
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (Photo *)associatedPhotoForThumbnailButton:(UIButton *)thumbnailButton
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(thumbnailButton,
                                    &kThumbnailButtonAssociatedPhotoKey);
}
```

Now we can easily set/get the associated photo for a button:

```
- (void)configureThumbnailButtonForPhoto:(Photo *)photo
{
    // ...
    [self setAssociatedPhoto:photo
          forThumbnailButton:thumbnailButton];
    // ...
}

- (void)thumbnailButtonTapped
{
    Photo *photo = [self associatedPhotoForThumbnailButton:thumbnailButton];
    // ...
}
```

[Blog post about tags and associated references](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIButton`.

In your subclass, add a new property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *tagCREATED_BY_ME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).

Or if you wanted to stick to the KISS principle - subclass UIButton and create a property.